# How to execute a ros callback just once

Tags: kinect, openni, callback, camera, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to subscribe to openni's "camera/rgb/camera_info" topic to get the camera matrix. Since the matrix doesn't change, I would like to execute the callback just once. How could I achieve this? Is the only way to unsubscribe? Or is it possible to use a ros service for this?

Regards,

Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62176/how-to-execute-a-ros-callback-just-once/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since camera_info is published with every image frame, the simplest solution is to subscribe to it. In you message callback: collect the data, then unsubscribe.

It is possible your callback may run a few more times after you unsubscribe. Just to be safe, set a flag when you unsubscribe and return immediately if you get called again.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-04-18**:
What is the reason for the callback running a few more times after unsubscribing?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A service is better suited for this indeed but than you probably have to create a subscriber node which advertises this service. Perhaps you can also set a variable after the first time the callback is called that prevents executing of the other callback code.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-04-18**:
A service only makes sense if both sides of the communication is nodes written by you. If the publisher is some other library then it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this question has been answered by @joq, but that was quite some time ago.

Not sure when it was added, but I believe that `ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)` ([api docs](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html)) is a much more elegant solution when only needing a single message.

This function takes care of everything that @joq suggests, ie: subscribing, waiting for a message and then unsubcribing immediately. The caller does not need to maintain any state him or herself (ie: no flag handling, no additional callbacks to ignore).

See #q270298 for an example that shows how to use `ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4